# Adding a column to an Acumatica grid

Tags: erp, acumatica

What is the best way to add a column to a grid in Acumatica?  I've looked at the documentation, and I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of grid you are using.    As an example, lets say you are going to add a CreatedDate column to the details grid of Journal Transactions screen.

You will need to switch to design mode and open up the Aspx Control Tree and select the PXGrid node, click Add, and select Add Column to Grid to open the Add Grid Column dialog.

Find the field you want to add (in this case CreatedDateTime).  you can also create new cusomt field here by pressing Add.  Pick the correct Column Editor type  (like DateTimeEdit) and press OK

move the Column up and down using the left tree to put in position you want.

Validate and publish the project!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify existing grid which was created by Acumatica you'll need following steps:
1. Add field in DB ( optional )
2. Add filed description in DAC extension
3. Add column to page in customization engine, or manually imitate behavior of customization engine